# DataBound-like event in ReportViewer 

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Is there is any way I can access ReportViewer DataSet after it being filled?

There is no **DataBound** Event in ReportViewer so I can access the data.

What I'm Trying to achieve is :

1- access data before it's submitted to the report ... 
2- Get for example:`dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Price")`
3- Do Some Operation on it : `Dim newPrice = DoSomething(Price)`
4- assign `newPrice` data to a Report Parameter.
5- assign **Parameter Value** to a specific **Textbox** inside the Report.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you displaying your report? Is it from code-behind? Can you show the code?

Comment: no Code .... It's by Report Designer and datasource from DataSet. and what I'm trying to do is to access the dataset rows after data is binded and before Submitting Data to the Report. So I'm trying to achieve the DataBound Event approach in the report viewer.

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to achieve, and what you've tried so far. As it is the question doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: Details added in the question.